# Data structure for trees

Tags: python, data-structures, functional-programming, tree

I noticed that `Python` has quite a lot specialities for working with data structures (various iterators, generators, list comprehensions etc.).

Could you advise me some data structures that are useful for working with trees in `pythonic style`? The nodes in the tree would contain some data and there would be classical operations like `children`, `siblings`, etc. You can present some python special features dealing with trees with some smart examples (e.g. functional approach to programming)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a good Python Tree data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009935/looking-for-a-good-python-tree-data-structure)

Comment: @Wooble my question is about functional features of working with trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm) API, which is implemented in the [Python standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and in the [LXML](http://lxml.de) library. It's meant for XML processing, but you can also use it for handling tree-structured data in general (and get XML serialization for free).

Comment: And could you demonstrate some functional features with data structures you're recommending?

Comment: @xralf: there are no zippers or other FP-style constructs in the API itself, but you can always write functional programs on top of it and you get the declarative language XPath for free.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs for [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/), a python toolkit for handling graph-based data structures, including trees.

Answer (score 1):

The [ETE toolkit](http://ete.cgenomics.org) implements many high level operations for tree data structures, from traversing functions or node annotation to tree image generation. You may want to take a look at [its tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a port of clojure's zip library for python.

https://github.com/trivio/zipper

It's an immutable data structure which always returns a new result for each operation. 
Perfect for functional programming or when you want to preserve a history of edits made to a tree.

You can  manipulate any tree that can be described with 3 functions:

**branch(node):** returns true if the node can have children

**children(node):** returns a tuple of the node's children

**make_node(node, children):** Constructs a new node to replace current node after it's children have been modified.