# Python: create a nested dictionary from a list of parent child values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, treeview

Here is the input:

```
list_child_parent= [
    #first value is child, second is parent
    (0, 1),
    (1, 3),
    (8, 7),
    (3, 6),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 3)
]
```

The output needs to create a nested dictionary tree using these values. The tree will never be more than 6 levels deep.

For example:

```
output_dict = {
    6: {3: {1: {0: {}}, 4: {}, 5: {}}}, 7: {8: {}}
}
```

I have spent two days trying to accomplish this. I have tried writing functions to find where the key is in the tree and then add the new key after it, but I cannot produce code that can continue more than 3 levels. It's baffling and I feel that there is probably a standard library that can do this.

My experience level is low.

Comment: According to your 'example output' 3 is the parent of 8. But that's not what your input describes. Further, isn't 8 supposed to be the *child* of 7 ? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the `key: value` pairs?

Comment: 3 is the parent of 1, 4, and 5. Yes 8 is the child of 7 and I fixed that. Obviously I don't have the code that produces the output yet so I wrote that dictionary by hand.

Comment: There is no pattern to the pairs. You should assume that the list of parent child lairs can be in any order.

Comment: so that means there can be several possible outcomes from processing your input list? I think you need to explain what you are trying to do better. To me it seems like your asking to build a randomly structured dictionary, which could be achieved in a great number of ways.

Comment: No there is only one possible outcome. The input list is always the same, but it could be in any order.

Comment: If you have code that's not working like you expect, it's a good idea to post it. One way to solve your problem might be to make a dictionary of the children of each element (just the number) and also keep track of elements which you haven't seen a parent for yet. Then you can start with the parentless elements and build the nested dictionary.

Comment: Basically what I've tried so far is to iterate through the list and add the parent key if it doesn't exist. If the parent key does exist I put the child underneath it. However my code starts throwing key errors when I go beyond three levels deep

Comment: My code is hard to read because the input list comes from a database and there are many classes and sub classes involved. I will try to modify it so you can see my approach but it is exactly how I described above

Comment: You should try to  make an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which removes the unnecessary stuff and focuses only on this problem.

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement a tree in Python? Are there any built in data structures in Python like in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358045/how-can-i-implement-a-tree-in-python-are-there-any-built-in-data-structures-in) and also [Looking for a good Python Tree data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009935/looking-for-a-good-python-tree-data-structure)

Comment: AMR, I already know how the tree must be implemented. It has to be a nested dictionary. I'm trying to figure out how to create the dictionary.

Comment: Shouldn't your tree be `{6: {3: {1: {0: {}}, 4: {}, 5: {}}}, 7: {8: {}}}`?  You show 3 has childeren 1, 5, 4 in the tuples, but the output makes it seem like 1 has childs 5, 4, 0.

Comment: @DanSafee Then you didn't read far enough down. On "How Can I Implement..." do `Command` + `F` and search for `nested dict`. On "Looking for a good..."  `Command` + `F` and search for `dicts of dicts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not pretty and probably not Pythonic, but it should get you going:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def make_map(list_child_parent):
    has_parent = set()
    all_items = {}
    for child, parent in list_child_parent:
        if parent not in all_items:
            all_items[parent] = {}
        if child not in all_items:
            all_items[child] = {}
        all_items[parent][child] = all_items[child]
        has_parent.add(child)

    result = {}
    for key, value in all_items.items():
        if key not in has_parent:
            result[key] = value
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_child_parent = [
        #first value is child, second is parent
        (0, 1),
        (1, 3),
        (8, 7),
        (3, 6),
        (4, 3),
        (5, 3)
    ]

    actual = make_map(list_child_parent)

    expected = {
        6: {
            3: {
                1: {
                    0: {}
                },
                4: {},
                5: {}
            }
        },
        7: {
            8: {}
        }
    }
    print('OK' if expected == actual else 'FAIL')
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. It condensed my 45 lines of code that didn't work into a simple solution that is easy to understand. I have never seen set() used in that manner before, and your usage would not be obvious after reading the python docs. I should note, that once the tree is built, it is saved in cache and so performance is not an issue. However there are several thousand parent/child relationships and periodically the tree needs to be rebuilt as new data is added. This will probably run as cron for a flask website that I'm building.

Comment: Can you please help with the reverse i.e. making parent child pairs from the same nested dictionary?

Comment: @user3156040 The answer probably won't fit in a comment. Could you please create a new question and then post the link here?

Answer (score 2):

This code will convert a tree from the given format into a tree structured dictionary.  It's a lot of fluf, but it helps to keep track of what is happening.  Performance wise it's pretty good.

```
LIST_CHILD_PARENTS = [                                                     
#first value is child, second is parent                                    
(0, 1),                                                                    
(1, 3),                                                                    
(8, 7),                                                                    
(3, 6),                                                                    
(4, 3),                                                                    
(5, 3)                                                                     
]                                                                          


class Node(object):                                                        
    def __init__(self, value):                    
        self.value = value
        # List of references to Node()'s.                                                
        self.child = []              
        # Reference to parent Node()                                                                           
        self.parent = None                                               
    def set_parent(self, parent):                                          
        self.parent = parent                                               
    def set_child(self, child):                                            
        self.child.append(child)                                           


def get_a_root(items):                                                     
    """Find a root node from items.                                        

    Grab some node and follow the parent pointers to a root.               
    """                                                                    
    cur_key = list(items.keys())[0]                                              
    while items[cur_key].parent is not None:                               
        cur_key = items[cur_key].parent.value                              
    parent = items[cur_key]                                                
    return parent                                                          

def extract_tree(items, root):                                             
    """Remove the tree from root in items.                                 
    """                                                                    
    cur_key = root.value                                                   
    this_node = items[cur_key]                                             
    if len(this_node.child) == 0:                                          
        items.pop(cur_key)                                                 
        return                                                             
    else:                                                                  
        for child in this_node.child:                                      
            extract_tree(items, child)                                     
        items.pop(cur_key)                                                  

def insert_from_root(tree, root):                                          
    """Insert the dictionary items from a tree.                            
    """                                                                    
    current = root                                                         
    if len(current.child) == 0:                                            
        tree[current.value] = {}                                           
        return                                                             
    else:                                                                  
        table = {}                                                         
        for child in current.child:                                        
            insert_from_root(table, child)                                 
        tree[current.value] = table                                                                                                

def build_graphs():                                                        
    """Map all input graphs into Node(object)'s.           

    Return: A hash table by value: Node(value, child, parent)              
    """                                                                    
    items = {}                                                             
    for child, parent in LIST_CHILD_PARENTS:                               
        if not child in items:                                       
            c_n = Node(child)  
            items[child] = c_n                 
        else:                                                              
            c_n = items[child]                                             
        if not parent in items:                                      
            p_n = Node(parent) 
            items[parent] = p_n                    
        else:                                                              
            p_n = items[parent]                                            
        p_n.set_child(c_n)                                                 
        c_n.set_parent(p_n)                                                                                       
    return items                                                           

def run_dict_builder():                                                    
    """Map the graphs from input and map into a dict.                                  

    Sequence:                                                              
        1- Map all graphs from input trees: list(tuple)             
        2- For each root node:                                             
            2A - Get a root node.                                      
            2B - Extract tree under this root from graphs list.                  
            2C - Insert the tree from this root into dict.                      
        3- Return the Dictionary Tree structure.                                                     
    """                                                                    
    graphs = build_graphs()                                                

    h_table = {}                                                           
    while len(graphs) > 0:                                                 
        root = get_a_root(graphs)                                          
        extract_tree(graphs, root)                                
        insert_from_root(h_table, root)                          
    return h_table                                                         

print(run_dict_builder())
```

Comment: Matt, thank you for contributing a very fine solution. This worked, but I need to use it in a python 3 environment (should have specified - sorry!). How would I change items.has_key on line 67 to make it work with python 3? `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'`

Comment: @DanSafee You could use:   `if parent in items:` instead.  `if key in dict:`

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question was answered a long time ago I wanted to give another solution that, to me, seems quite a bit cleaner. I mostly use this with lists of parents and children that get zipped together. For example

```
parents = [None, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 6, 6, 1, 9, 10, 10, 9, 13, 13]
children = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

# {1: {2: {3: {4: {}, 5: {}}, 6: {7: {}, 8: {}}}, 9: {10: {11: {}, 12: {}}, 13: {14: {}, 15: {}}}}}
```

### Implementation:

```
def create_tree(node_map, root=None):
""" Given a list of tuples (child, parent) return the nested dictionary representation.
"""

def traverse(parent, node_map, seen):
    children = {}
    for edge in node_map:
        if edge[1] == parent and edge[0] not in seen:
            seen.add(edge[0])
            children[edge[0]] = traverse(edge[0], node_map, seen)
    return children

return traverse(root, node_map, {root})
```

### Usage:

Example of root the exclusion.

We want the root to be "a" but is excluded because a root should be indicated as having no parent (`None`).

```
parents = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "e"]
children = ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
edges = list(zip(children, parents))
test_tree = create_tree(edges, "a")
print(test_tree)
# result {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}, 'f': {}}, 'e': {'g': {}, 'h': {}}}
```

Adding the root with no parent designates the node as the root.

```
parents = [None, "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "e"]
children = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
edges = list(zip(children, parents))
test_tree = create_tree(edges, None)
print(test_tree)
# result: {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}, 'f': {}}, 'e': {'g': {}, 'h': {}}}}
```

Multiple trees can be represented by having multiple roots.

```
parents = [None, "a", "b", "c", None, "b", "e", "e"]
children = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
edges = list(zip(children, parents))
test_tree = create_tree(edges, None)
print(test_tree)
# result: {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}, 'f': {}}}, 'e': {'g': {}, 'h': {}}}
```

To get the desired output from the original post we find and designate the roots.

```
edges = [
    #first value is child, second is parent
    (0, 1),
    (1, 3),
    (8, 7),
    (3, 6),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 3)
]
roots = {edge[1] for edge in edges} - {edge[0] for edge in edges}
edges += [(root, None) for root in roots]
test_tree = create_tree(edges, None)
print(test_tree)
# result: {6: {3: {1: {0: {}}, 4: {}, 5: {}}}, 7: {8: {}}}
```