# Where to keep data from hierarchical clustering in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am hierarchically clustering gene expression data. My result data is shaped like dendrogram. I want to keep the whole tree in some data structure in python and do some calculations in each node (I think recursively). For every node I know the genes in there and some extra information (GO, p-values etc..)
Do you have any suggestions on how to store this kind of data in python in a way that I can traverse the whole tree?
My first thought was a list of dictionaries:

```
clusters=[{'id': 1, 'cluster': [gen1, gen2,...], 'size': ... , 'ChildIDs': ... , 'ParentID': ... , 'distance': ..., 'score': ...}, {'id': 2, ...}, ... ]
```

But since the clusters are nested, then storing the genes for every cluster is not efficient, I think.

If anyone has a better idea how to keep this kind of info, I would appreciate it:)

Comment: You could maybe take a look to [this implementation of hierarchical clustering](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/cluster/gaac.html). It stores the information in a [Dendogram class](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/cluster/util.html). If you look at the method `show` of the class `Dendogram` you might get an idea of what it is doing. I don't know how many genes you're talking about, probably a lot, and how efficient this implementation will be... Hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing your own datastructure, `collections.defaultdict` might be appropriate for a tree. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260480/5293595).

Comment: Thanks!


I'm not sure that I can get the 'cluster' out from this structure. 
The problem is, that I have like 23000 genes as leaves, the root cluster has all the genes, the next child cluster has less genes from these 23000 etc ...
If I know I want to see the genes from cluster with id:3, then how could that be done? 


I think it is best to keep the gene names only once as leafs and then according to cluster id I would get the names.

I'm quite new to this kind of structures.

Comment: Sorry, I only have a vague idea of what you're against, but would hashing a set (`frozenset`) or dictionary be a viable option to store a reference that can be decoded, compared etc.?