# Tree traversal and getting neighbouring child nodes in Python

Tags: python, tree, spacy

I'm trying to traverse a tree, and get certain subtrees into a particular data structure. I think an example is the best way to explain it:

[image]

For this tree, I want the root node and it's children. Then any children that have their own children should be traversed in the same way, and so on. So for the above tree, we would end up with a data structure such as:

```
[
    (a, [b, c]),
    (c, [d, e, f]),
    (f, [g, h]),
]
```

I have some code so far to produce this, but there's an issue that it stops too early (or that's what it seems like):

```
from spacy.en import English


def _subtrees(sent, root=None, subtrees=[]):
    if not root:
        root = sent.root

    children = list(root.children)
    if not children:
        return subtrees

    subtrees.append((root, [child for child in children]))
    for child in children:
        return _subtrees(sent, child, subtrees)


nlp = English()
doc = nlp('they showed us an example')
print(_subtrees(list(doc.sents)[0]))
```

Note that this code won't produce the same tree as in the image. I feel like a generator would be better suited here also, but my generator-fu is even worse than my recursion-fu.

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009935/looking-for-a-good-python-tree-data-structure)?

Comment: No, but looking through it now, while I see lots of tree-traversal in general, nothing that has inspired me to be able to fix my problem.

Comment: Can You provide a complete runnable example at the end of Your question, even maybe with an example input so we can copy-pase it into an editor and try to work on it?

Comment: I edited my code to be runnable, requires spacy (from pypi).

Comment: The tree data structure is not obvious from the code. Can print out `repr(list(doc.sents)[0])`, and show the results?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first sketch the recursive algorithm:

- Given a tree node, return:

  1. A tuple of the node with its children
  2. The subtrees of each child.

That's all it takes, so let's convert it to pseudocode, ehm, python:

```
def subtrees(node):
    if not node.children:
        return []

    result = [ (node.dep, list(node.children)) ]
    for child in node.children:
        result.extend(subtrees(child))

    return result
```

The root is just a node, so it shouldn't need special treatment. But please fix the member references if I misunderstood the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
def _subtrees(root):

   subtrees=[]
   queue = []
   queue.append(root)
   while(len(queue)=!0):
      root=queue[0]
      children = list(root.children)
      if (children):
         queue = queue + list(root.children)
         subtrees.append((root.dep, [child.dep for child in children]))
      queue=queue.pop(0)

   return subtrees
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to know this for using spaCy specifically, why not just:

```
[(word, list(word.children)) for word in sent]
```

The Doc object lets you iterate over all nodes in order. So you don't need to walk the tree recursively here --- just iterate.

Comment: I guess this doesn't quite do what I want, as I don't want to have empty lists (where the node has no children), but I can probably process these out. While I have you, is there some way to ignore punctuation when tokenising?  Sometimes it's good for my results, but sometimes it just introduces noise.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite comment yet, but if you modify the response by @syllogism_ like so and it'll omit all nodes that haven't any children in them.

```
[(word, list(word.children)) for word in s if bool(list(word.children))]
```