# Tree Implementation in Python

Tags: python

I found two similar questions(infact same question) for implementing tree in python. Can anyone point me to good references to implement trees. The link given in previous answers is not working.Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? What about the top rated answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2482602/391531) didn't work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Comment: Define "not working"  Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a look at the samples provided by [MIT Open CourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm). The [Introduction to Algorithms Lecture Notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2008/lecture-notes/) may prove helpful.

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. I finally implemented tree in python.