# How to add a grandchild to a python tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, tree

I'm trying to implement a `Tree` in python, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482602/a-general-tree-implementation-in-python) thread and tried to work my own tree, but I got stuck at how to add grand childrens.

the tree I'm trying to construct is like:

```
Root
    ch1
        ch2
            ch3
            ch4
```

So I figured that the `add_child()` method should be recursive:

1, If the tree has no children, add children to Root

2, for each children of Root, if one of the children equals `parent`, add children to it and stop the loop(so the new child is actually a grand child).

3, if there is no match, call `add_child()` on the current children.

But my code gives me:

```
Root
    ch1
        ch2
            ch3
                ch4
```

Btw, **every time** I work with recursive algorithms I get confused, could anyone give me some good advice of how to write recursive codes? or is there any good tutorials?

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = parent

    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t" * level + repr(self.data) + "\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__repr__(level + 1)
        return ret

    def add_child(self, node, parent):

        if self.children == []:
            self.children.append(node)
            return

        for child in self.children:
            if child == parent:
                child.children.append(node)
                return
            else:
                child.add_child(node, parent)

        # self.children.append(node)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tree = Node('Root')
    tree.add_child(Node('ch1'), 'Root')
    tree.add_child(Node('ch2'), 'ch1')
    tree.add_child(Node('ch3'), 'ch2')
    tree.add_child(Node('ch4'), 'ch2')
    print tree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following section makes no sense:

```
if self.children == []:
    self.children.append(node)
    return
```

If a node has no children you automatically add the node to that node? What if the node should be added to a different parent?

You probably meant to write:

```
def add_child(self, node, parent):
    if self.data == parent:
        self.children.append(node)
        return
    for child in self.children:
        child.add_child(node, parent)
```

which produces the tree as expected.

Comment: It works! thanks, btw can you give me some advice about writing/debugging recursive programs? Anything would help, I'm so frustrated about this...

Comment: @shengy: practise often and try to keep the data structure in mind. What needs to happen at a node and where does data need to go? For example: do I need to pass information in the recursive call and what information do I need to return from a recursive call?